# Class containing a list of derived classes

Tags: python, class, inheritance

Supposing I have the following base and derived classes, exemplifying a basic case of class inheritance:

```
class base(object): 
    type   = []                  
    def __init__(self,arg1,arg2):
        self.m1 = arg1
        self.m2 = arg2

class derivedA(base):    # inherits from base
    type = 'A'  
    base.type.append('A')
    def value(self,arg):
        return arg*0.345

class derivedB(base):
    type   = 'B'
    base.type.append('B')
    def value(self,arg):
        return arg*0.186
```

Now suppose I want to define another class that holds a list of any of the classes derived from `base` as a member:

```
class container(object):
    def __init__(self,dim=None,tp=None):
        assert dim>=0
        if dim==0:
            self.dim = 0
            self.lst = [ ]
            self.mlt = [ ] 
        else:
            assert tp!=None
            self.dim = dim
            self.lst = [base(0,0) for _ in range(dim)] # how to call generic constructor of class?
            self.mlt = [1.0] * dim

    def printVals(self,value):
        for d in self.lst:
            print(d.value(value))
```

How would I be able to generically deduce the adequate constructor from the type `tp` passed as argument? As it is, it only instantiates a list of `base` class members:

```
gg = container(10,derivedA.type)
gg.printVals(0.5) # 'base' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Comment: I don't see why you have that `type` list at all. What was the purpose of that?

Comment: Remnants of past attempts to solve the issue. I guess my objective was to assert that the argument `tp` was valid, i.e. `assert tp in base.type` or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the feeling you're not quite used to the fact that classes are objects in Python. You don't need strings as placeholders for classes. You can just pass classes around directly.

All that `type` stuff is pointless. Pass classes directly:

```
class Base(object): 
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.m1 = arg1
        self.m2 = arg2

class DerivedA(Base):
    def value(self, arg):
        return arg*0.345

class DerivedB(Base):
    def value(self, arg):
        return arg*0.186

class Container(object):
    def __init__(self, dim=None, tp=None):
        if dim is not None and dim < 0:
            raise ValueError('dim must be positive')
        if not dim:
            self.dim = 0
            self.lst = []
            self.mlt = [] 
        else:
            if tp is None:
                raise TypeError('tp must be provided if dim is provided')
            self.dim = dim
            self.lst = [tp(0, 0) for _ in range(dim)]
            self.mlt = [1.0] * dim

    def print_vals(self, value):
        for d in self.lst:
            print(d.value(value))

gg = Container(10, DerivedA)
gg.print_vals(0.5)
```

Note the use of `DerivedA` instead of `derivedA.type` in the `Container` call, and the `tp(0, 0)` call in the `Container` constructor.